# numpy having no "isin" attribute

Tags: python, numpy

I tried using the np.isin() function but everytime I do, it returns me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

here is exactly what I do

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
test = np.arange(5)
print np.isin(a, test)
```

I havent found any information about this problem, I use the latest version of numpy and havent had any problem with other numpy module, why does it returns me this error?

Comment: shouldn't it be `np.sin()` ?

Comment: @ksai No, user is asking for `np.isin`. @Tissuebox It works for me in Python3.

Comment: np.sin() returns the sinus of a number, np.isin() is a completly different thing

Comment: @Tissuebox. It was a close call between "imaginary sinus" and "is in" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading through the Notes section of the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) shows

> New in version 1.13.0.

I suspect that if you do

```
print(np.__version__)
```

you will see something less than `1.13.0`.

Answer (score 17):

The `isin` function was added in [NumPy 1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#new-functions):

> New `np.isin` function, improves on `in1d`.

You're probably using an older version.

Answer (score 8):

Following the [source] link in the docs I find that:

```
def isin(element, test_elements, assume_unique=False, invert=False):
    "..."
    element = np.asarray(element)
    return in1d(element, test_elements, assume_unique=assume_unique,
                invert=invert).reshape(element.shape)
```

It's not doing anything that you can't already do with `in1d`.

The containing file can be downloaded, and used from your own directory.  It has an enhanced `unique`.