# How can i turn values i don't need to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 0 6 6 6 6]
     [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
     [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 0 0 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 6 6]
     [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
     [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
     [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]]
```

As a first step i transformed all none 0 elements to 1 using this line :

```
 binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(bool).astype(int)
```

but i couldn't adjust that line to meet a different requirement as 
now i want to transform all the numbers except a given ones to 0, it may be 1 element, it may be all of them so i'll have to use a list let's say :

```
elements_to_keep = [2,4]
```

so all the 1,3,5,6,7 will be transformed to 0 and i'll have the values of 4 and 2 in my matrix intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.isin`:

```
data = numpy.arange(7)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
data[~numpy.isin(data, elements_to_keep)] = 0
# array([0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0])
```

As for `binary_transform`, instead of casting to `bool` and back you can also just assign the new values

```
data[data != 0] = 1
```

or use `numpy.sign`

```
data = numpy.sign(data)
```

Comment: Got this error `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'isin'`.

Comment: @Nelly see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045031/numpy-having-no-isin-attribute). You're using a version of numpy < 1.13

Answer (score 1):

A solution which does not use `numpy.isin`:

```
def keep_only(data, to_keep):
    """ keep only the values in to_keep """
    import numpy as np

    mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=bool)
    for elem in to_keep:
        mask[data==elem] = True

    return data * mask

# testing
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(5, size=36).reshape(6,6) # use your data here
elements_to_keep = [2,4] # use your values here

new_data = keep_only(data, elements_to_keep)
```

Comment: It's giving me `None` as output.

Comment: I just made sure to run this exact snippet by copying and pasting it into a pristine iPython shell, and it ran fine. I added an numpy import at the top to avoid any errors related to the `np.random.randint` call.

Comment: i tried it on the following `labels = np.array([[0,1,2,3],[5,6,0,1,2],[2,3,4]])`

Comment: What is `labels` supposed to be? The elements to keep?

Comment: That is no matrix. It has a varying number of elements per row. Is that supposed to be a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.DataFrame and applymap for filtering elementwise

```
import pandas as pd
values_to_keep = [2,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).applymap(lambda x: 1 if x in values_to_keep else 0)
data = df.values
```